# Remove null and empty values using collect with string array

Tags: groovy

I've got a simple form that I'm trying to retrieve the values from. Except I want to remove the null or empty values from the collection. An example output that I'm getting is:

```
joey:admin:null::155:null
```

You can see values are coming through as null and one of the values is empty (the one with the two colons). What am I doing wrong I thought if I checked the size and the null check it wouldn't come through? Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
String generateValues() {
        return request.requestParameterMap
            .findAll { key, value -> !(key in ["honeypot", "confirm"]) }      
            .collect { k, v -> if(v != null && v.size() > 0) v[0]
}.join(",")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't check results of `.collect`. Also this closure will return nulls for empty keys (no `else` section).

Try this:

```
return request.requestParameterMap
    .findAll { key, value -> !(key in ["honeypot", "confirm"]) }      
    .collect { k, v -> if(v != null && v.size() > 0) v[0] }
    .findAll { x -> x != null && x.length() > 0 }
}.join(",")
```

or use `.findResults` instead of `.collect`:

```
return request.requestParameterMap
    .findAll { key, value -> !(key in ["honeypot", "confirm"]) }      
    .findResults { k, v -> v?.size() > 0 && v[0]?.length() > 0 ? v[0] : null }
}.join(",")
```